# Show track no in windows 7 media center

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium, and am quite fond of the media center software.

One thing that really bugs me, though: the media center does not show the track number of the songs.

This information I really miss, is there any way to get the media center to show the track #? In navigation as well as in "current playing".

Thanks.

Comment: Where should it show the track number?

Comment: Well, right next to the title, where else?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any column header, click "Choose Columns", and select "Track number".

Comment: Steve, you are probably thinking Windows Media Player, but my Question is about the Windows Media *Center*.